# std::wstring to QString conversion with Hiragana

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qstring

I'm trying to convert text containing Hiragana from a **wstring** to a **QString**, so that it can be used on a label's text property. However my code is not working and I'm not sure why that is.

The following conversion method obviously tells me that I made something wrong:

```
std::wstring myWString = L"Some Hiragana: あ い う え お";
ui->label->setText(QString::fromStdWString(myWString));
```

**Output:** Some Hiragana: ã‚ ã„ ã† ãˆ ãŠ

I can print Hiragana on a label if I put them in a string directly:

```
ui->label->setText("Some Hiragana: あ い う え お");
```

**Output:** Some Hiragana: あ い う え お

That means I can avoid this problem by simply using std::string instead of std::wstring, but I'd like to know why this is happening.

Comment: There's some weird UTF-8 <-> Windows-1252 shenanigans going on, what is the encoding of the source file, and what compiler are you using?

Comment: The file encoding is UTF-8 and the compiler is Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0 (x86).

Comment: Have you tried `QString::fromWCharArray( myWString.c_str());` and `myString.toUtf8()`?

Comment: @Laszlo Papp I tried that before and it leads to the same result. I think my Qt doesn't like UTF-8. ^^

Comment: @user3582665: ok, you did not mention, so was just double checking. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS is interpreting the file as Windows-1252 instead of UTF-8.

As an example, 'あ' in UTF-8 is `E3 81 82`, but the compiler is reading each byte as a single Windows-1252 char before converting it to the respective UTF-16 codepoints `E3 201A`, which works out as 'ã‚' (`81` is either ignored by VS as it is reserved in Windows-1252, or not printed by qt if VS happens to convert it to the respective C1 control character).

The direct version works because the compiler doesn't perform any conversions and leaves the string as `E3 81 82`.

To fix your issue you will need to inform VS that the file is UTF-8, according to other posts one way is to ensure the file has a UTF-8 BOM.

The only portable way of fixing this is to use escape sequences instead:

```
L"Some Hiragana: \u3042 \u3044 \u3046 \u3048 \u304A"
```

Comment: @user657267 Thank you for the helpful explanation. Everything makes sense now.

Comment: Well, that is not the only portable way. The OP could also use Qt directly since it is kind of the purpose for Qt. ;)

Comment: @LaszloPapp It is the only portable way, the representation of any character outside the basic source character set ([lex.charset]) is implementation defined.

Comment: I do not follow, the OP could use QString directly. In fact, he wrote in the question that works, and that is likely what should be done here instead of other workarounds. Well, If it was me to decide, I would do like that to avoid the pain. :)

Comment: @Laszlo Papp I wished that would work.

    QString myQString = "Some Hiragana: あ い う え お";
    ui->label->setText(myQString);

Output: Some Hiragana: ? ? ? ? ?

Comment: @LaszloPapp It works because the compiler left those values alone during translation of the source file, it will probably work on most compilers without a hitch, that still doesn't mean the standard guarantees it will.

Comment: @user657267: nor does the standard say otherwise... Anyway, you are free to show an implemention which gets it wrong. I have just tested some compilers Qt supports, and works fine. Even if there was one that is not supported by Qt, it does not matter in Qt software. It is bad idea in qt software to mess with wstring, in cases like this.

Comment: @user3582665: are you using some library where wstring is inevitable?

Comment: @Laszlo Papp Luckily not. :) I'm just learning C++/Qt and I read somewhere that it's good to use wstring on Windows OS.

Comment: I just installed a new compiler (MinGW 4.8.2 32bit) and it fixed everything. I compiled the project once with MinGW and the hiragana were displayed correctly from a wstring conversion. Then I switched back to MSVC2013 compiler, and even there were no more encoding issues. I guess MSVC2013 didn't want to get replaced. ^^ Thanks again everyone.